How to download file from OneDrive, the one Iìve got with my Office 365 subscription
I'm sorry, but I'm lost.
I have installed the latest OneDrive module by
Install-Module -Name OneDrive -RequiredVersion 2.2.8
So I try to get authenticated by
$Authentication=Get-ODAuthentication -ClientID "2EEB406877EE70E2"
since I can access my OneDrive folder at
https://onedrive.live.com/?id=root&cid=2EEB406877EE70E2
assuming that ClientID=cid.
However, I get the message
unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.
Azure Portal? I'm dealing with the OneDrive I've got with my Office 365 subscription.
Thanks a lot for the help.
